# Identification of cloudy days based on Net Radiation data

Tags: r, gis, atmosphere, solar

How can I identify that a particular day is cloudy or clear sky based on the daily time series of Net Radiation (calculated at FluxNet/AMERIFlux sites)? I read somewhere that clear sky radiation has sinusoidal behavior. If we get different behavior that means it is induced by clouds. I don't know how exactly approach this problem? Here is the sample data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1YfWgPbg3fxhFG1DTNH9Ex3lTDqLBZp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That sounds like an interesting problem raghav. What's your programming question?

Comment: I have to separate cloudy days and clear sky days based on the daily time series of Net Radiation.

Comment: Yes raghav, but Stack Overflow is a forum for asking about specific programming problems like unexpected errors or difficulties in getting a specific function to work. It's not the place to ask general questions about what approach you should take to data manipulation, even if you intend to use programming as part of that solution. Do you have any example data or code that you have tried yet?

Comment: Yes Cameron, I have updated the question with sample data. I can program the problem if I know how to approach it. I think this is an outlier/anomaly detection problem but I'm still not sure how to approach it?

Comment: i have so many questions:
1) how many clouds (as in what area needs to be cloudy - in km²) constitute "cloudy"? 
2) do you have a difference in sunshine hours?
3) do you have data for a completely overcast(cloudy) day and data for a completely free sky to use as a reference (would probably need one for every season)
4) what underlying question do you want to answer
5) do you have pseudo-code?
6) do you have temperature data for cross-referencing?
7) did you read some papers concerning the topic?

Comment: My question was that can be identify cloudy days if we have given measured point solar radiation data only?  The underlying logic is that if measured radiation exhibits a smooth sinusoidal variation that means it belongs to clear sky day otherwise cloudy day (Note: It is an approximation). I have read few papers (e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038092X14006197) that write that cloud can be identified solely based on radiation data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take your raw data and convert the `Time` column from text into actual dates we can work with, this will help the analysis. We will also remove the rows with `NaN` values:

```r
df <- read.csv("net_rad.csv")

df$Date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df$Time, "%m/%d/%Y"))
df <- df[!is.nan(df$NET_RAD),]
```

If we plot the daily net radiation we see a clear seasonal pattern:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Date, NET_RAD)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

We could use a seasonal decomposition to see these seasonal effects and even remove them:

```r
net_rad_ts <- ts(df$NET_RAD, frequency = 365)
net_rad_decomp <- stats::decompose(net_rad_ts)
plot(net_rad_decomp)
```

[image]

We can see that as well as the seasonal variation, there is a background trend and considerable random variation within each season. We can also see that the variance appears to be higher in summer than in winter (which makes sense)

Without a clear cut-off to define what "cloudy" means in terms of the net radiation, we can simply specify that we want to identify days when the solar radiation was below average after accounting for time of year and trend over time. So we can do:

```r
df$cloudy <- as.logical(net_rad_decomp$random < 0)
```

This allows us to plot the data showing the days that were unseasonably bright in yellow, and those that were unseasonably dim  in gray:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Date, NET_RAD, colour = cloudy)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("gold", "gray40")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

This gives us a rough approximation to your answer that will have to suffice until you work out a good definition of "cloudy"

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. Defining cloud is subjective. I was approaching the problem based on outlier detection in moving window of 15 days (based on +-2sigma rule). Actually, I just wanted a rough approximation as you explained.